# Fpdf Chinese characters showing random character outputs

Tags: pdf, fonts, character, fpdf, cjk

I have just converted my chinese fonts (simhei) via fpdf makefont to postscript so that I can
use them in my fpdf output. So once I implement my Chinese text into my files, the characters
showing are random characters other than the ones I typed.

Here is is the code:

```
$pdf2 = new PDF_Chinese('P', 'cm', 'Letter');
$pdf2->AliasNbPages();
$pdf2->AddGBFont('simhei','黑体');
$pdf2->AddGBFont('simkai','楷体_GB2312');

$pdf2->AddPage();

$pdf2->SetCompression(false);

$pdf2->SetAutoPageBreak(1,3);

$pdf2->SetDrawColor(200,200,200);

$pdf2->SetFont('simhei','',20.5);

$pdf2->Cell(0,1,'Black Bomb 目录批发价格 (批发)',0,0,'C');
$pdf2->SetFont('Arial','',7);`
```

[image: This is the result]

The characters are not the same as the ones in my code.
Could it be that there went something wrong when I converted the font? Using fpdf makefont?

I tried to use different text to check if any characters are in the correct place.
it seems like no characters would display as I put them in. Also Unicode characters,
didn't fix the problem

Comment: You should use tFPDF for Chinese support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Olivier This did the job. After using tFPDF my problem is solved.
Hereby I close this thread. Everybody who has problems adding Chinese characters
to FPDF please use tFPDF instead. http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

For simplified Chinese users. Please ignore all resources on the net, where people are explain how to convert Chinese fonts using TTFPT1.exe.

感谢 @Olivier.换到tFPDF解决的我的问题。 我现关闭这个讨论区。大家如果有问题加简体中文字使用FPDF请换成用tFPDF. 所有晚上的说明交给你们怎么换字母用TTFPT1.exe.可以忽视。